# IList<T>, IEnumerable<T> and ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, collections, .net-4.0, observablecollection

I have two classes defined like

```
public class PostleitzahlList : ObservableCollection<Postleitzahl> {
}

public class Postleitzahl : IPostleitzahl {
}
```

Now I have a Service-Class which contains

```
PostleitzahlList _postleitzahlList;
```

This Serviceclass has also to implement a Property of a Service-Interface which returns `_postleitzahlList` - but this Interface only knows `IPostleitzahl` - it doesn't know `PostleitzahlList` or `Postleitzahl`. this Property should be used for Binding in WPF.

I am trying now to declare and implement this Property. I have tried

```
    public ObservableCollection<IPostleitzahl> PostleitzahlList {
        get { return this._postleitzahlList; }
    }
```

and

```
    public IList<IPostleitzahl> PostleitzahlList {
        get { return this._postleitzahlList; }
    }
```

But both does not work.
The fallowing seems to work:

```
    public IEnumerable<IPostleitzahl> PostleitzahlList {
        get { return this._postleitzahlList; }
    }
```

I ask me now
1. why does the first and second try not working?
2. what is the best solution to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your PostleitzahlList to extend `ObservableCollection<IPostleitzahl>`? It seems to me you should use the interface instead of the implementation here.

Comment: Why not just `public PostleitzahlList PlList { get { return this._postleitzahlList; } }`. This should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with covariance. An `ObservableCollection<Postleitzahl>` isn't an `ObservableCollection<IPostleitzahl>`, and ditto with lists. Here's an example of why not:

```
ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();

// This is invalid, but it's what you're trying to do, effectively.
ObservableCollection<object> objects = strings;

// This would have to work... it's fine...
objects.Add(new object());

// And this should be fine too...
string x = strings[0];
```

... but as you can see, you're now trying to fetch a non-string reference and store it in a string variable. The only viable outcome would be an execution-time failure... and half the point of generics is to push error detection to *compile-time*.

Now `IEnumerable<T>` is *covariant* in `T` because you can't add any items via it - that makes it safe to apply that sort of conversion:

```
// There's nothing you can do to violate type safety here...
Observable<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

For more information, read up on [covariance and contravariance in generics in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Do you need the `IPostleitzahl` interface? If you just exposed the properties via `ObservableCollection<Postleitzahl>` or `IList<Postleitzahl>` it would be fine. Alternatively, you could change your variable to be an `ObservableCollection<IPostleitzahl>` and just happen to populate it by creating `Postleitzahl` instances.

Answer (score 0):

can you change PostleitzahlList to

```
public class PostleitzahlList : ObservableCollection<IPostleitzahl> {
}
```

with elementtype `IPostleitzahl` instead of `Postleitzahl`?

for explanation see @jon skeet answer

Comment: ouch - not a working link to a skeet answer. You just triggered the living legend instead:)